# The look-and-say sequence is the sequence

Tags: python

I try to generate a member of the sequence from the previous member, read off the digits of the
previous member, counting the number of digits in groups of the same digit. For example:

• 1 is read off as "one 1" or 11.

• 11 is read off as "two 1s" or 21.

• 21 is read off as "one 2, then one 1" or 1211.

• 1211 is read off as "one 1, one 2, then two 1s" or 111221.

• 111221 is read off as "three 1s, two 2s, then one 1" or 312211

the problem is the code print only first two number from each term!

```
def main():
    inputFilename=input("Input File name:")
    infile=open(inputFilename,'r')
    term= infile.readline()
    r=int(input("Enter how many terms in the sequences to generate: "))
    print("")

    for i in range(r-1):
       term=lookAndSay(term)
       print(term)

def lookAndSay(term):

    ruesult=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(term):
        count=1
        while i+1 < len(term) and term[i]==term[i+1]:
            i+=1
            count+=1
    ruesult.append(str(count)+term[i])
    i+=1
    return ''.join(ruesult)
main()
```

Comment: `ruesult.append(str(count)+term[i])` and `i += 1` are not properly indented - put them in the outer while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why 2 *while* loops are needed. I created a more straightforward (I'd say) implementation. The algorithm is simple, traverse the string, and every time the current character is the same as the previous, increment the counter, while when it changes, "save" the previous group and reinitialize the counter.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools as its
import sys


def look_and_say(s):
    if not s:
        return ""
    ret = []
    cur_count = 1
    for i, e in enumerate(s[1:], start=1):
        if e == s[i - 1]:
            cur_count += 1
        else:
            ret.append("{:d}{:s}".format(cur_count, s[i - 1]))
            cur_count = 1
    ret.append("{:d}{:s}".format(cur_count, s[-1]))
    return "".join(ret)


def look_and_say_its(s):
    return "".join("{:d}{:s}".format(len(list(g)), k) for k, g in its.groupby(s))


def main(*argv):
    datas = (
        "123751",
        "98211188",
    )
    func = look_and_say
    #func = look_and_say_its  # Decomment line to use this function
    print("Using function: {:s}".format(func.__name__))
    print("Random data:")
    for data in datas:
        print("{:s} - {:s}".format(data, func(data)))

    start_data = "1"
    iterations = 10
    print("\n{:d} iterations starting from '{:s}':".format(iterations, start_data))
    for _ in range(iterations):
        print("{:s} - ".format(start_data), end="")
        start_data = func(start_data)
        print(start_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Note that I also added a more elegant implementation (*look_and_say_its* which uses [[Python.Docs]: itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby))

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071897929]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Using function: look_and_say
> Random data:
> 123751 - 111213171511
> 98211188 - 1918123128
>
> 10 iterations starting from '1':
> 1 - 11
> 11 - 21
> 21 - 1211
> 1211 - 111221
> 111221 - 312211
> 312211 - 13112221
> 13112221 - 1113213211
> 1113213211 - 31131211131221
> 31131211131221 - 13211311123113112211
> 13211311123113112211 - 11131221133112132113212221
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in making code shorter until it's so short that errors can't hide...

```py
import itertools

def look_and_say(line):
    ii = itertools.groupby(line)
    return ''.join(f'{sum(1 for _ in i)}{char}' for char, i in ii)
```

Using it:

```py
> line = '1'
> for _ in range(10): print(line := look_and_say(line))
11
21
1211
111221
312211
13112221
1113213211
31131211131221
13211311123113112211
11131221133112132113212221
```